# zsh completion for all executables in path

Tags: linux, macos, bash, zsh, tab-completion

I have written a script which itself takes as an argument any arbitrary executable in my $PATH.  Is there a way to create a zsh (or bash) completion function such that I would be able to type `myFunc to[Tab]` and it would complete to `myFunc top` for example? Selecting only files which have executable permissions would be preferable, but having any and every file in $PATH would be more than helpful!

I can't imagine the system would matter, but this would be running on Linux, BSD, and Mac.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zsh` has a completion function for commands in `PATH` named `_path_commands`. You can configure the completion to use it for `myFunc` by running:

```
compdef _path_commands myFunc
```

---

*Note:* this requires that the *zsh completion system* to be initialized. Usually (as set up by `compinstall`) this happens in your `~/.zshrc` with

```
# some zstyle configurations

autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

Any calls to `compdef` need to be done after `compinit`. If you get "command not found" errors when running `compdef`, I suggest setting up the completion system with `compinstall`.

*Note:* for security, zsh will throw errors if any directories in your $fpath are world-writeable.  If you receive the error:

> zsh compinit: insecure directories, run compaudit for list. Ignore
>   insecure directories and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]?

Do not simply hit y, but hit n and then try `compaudit | xargs chmod g-w` as suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762280/zsh-compinit-insecure-directories

Comment: Great! Thank you! This worked perfectly.  I have also seen that some people use a "completions" directory to store varied completion heuristics.  Is this a compatible with that paradigm? If more complex completions were to be added are they generally kept out of the .zshrc? Thanks again!

Comment: I have removed the accepted answer tag because on linux (but curiously enough, not on Mac) trying to complete any function that is not myFunc results in the error "_complete:96: bad math expression: operand expected at `'" Example being typing ls [Tab] will give this error

Comment: I did test that on Linux. *Ubuntu* 14.04 with *zsh* 5.0.5, *Arch Linux* with *zsh* 5.0.6 and now even *TomatoUSB* with *zsh* 4.3.17 (alternate router firmware with ddwrt optware from nslu2). With my own configuration as well as without configuration (`zsh -f`). It worked fine in every case without breaking other completions. Might I suggest that something is wrong with *zsh* on your Linux machine, either configuration or in the installed package. Does everything work on your Linux, if you just leave out `compdef _path_commands myFunc`?

Comment: I will reaccept your answer as I have found the necessary changes to make it work.  My particular zsh setup had some directories in the fpath that had write permission which resulted in the error: "zsh compinit: insecure directories, run compaudit for list.
Ignore insecure directories and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]?"  Simply hitting 'y' results in the problem I had with your answer.  Running "compaudit | xargs chmod g-w" as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762280/solved the problem. Might I suggest editing your answer to include this possibility / solution?